# Ignore custom fields when INSERT INTO a view with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have created a view which is a `SELECT *` query with additional "calculated" fields from a table.

I have an application which use this view to select data, and which can INSERT data using this view.
I am not able to tell the application to use the table instead of the view to make the INSERT, but SQL Server can handle INSERT on views.

But in this case, when making an insert, the application automatically append all of the fields of the view to add them in the INSERT.
So the insert query fails because of the INSERT in the calculated fields.

Is it possible to add something like a "listener" on INSERT in a view to ignore or remove some fields from the INSERT query?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just specify the columns you want in your application INSERT? What is your code in the application? I don't think what you are asking is possible in a view, it would need to be a sproc.

Comment: You should never use select * in creating a view. What happens when the underlying table definitions change? And who says you can't insert into a view

Comment: `SELECT *` is just for a simpler explanation: I just select tables fields with extra calculated fields in the view. And I don't have access to to application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` `TRIGGER`. Something like:

```
CREATE VEW VW_YOUR_VIEW AS
    SELECT * FROM sys.objects
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_INSERT_YOUR_VIEW ON VW_YOUR_VIEW
INSTEAD OF INSERT
BEGIN
    --Your Real Insert
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
```

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Indead, just found the documentation about `INSTEAD OF INSERT` with a complete example: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Seb33300 added the link as a source